# how to manipulate css dynamically to make div move when div is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this bit of code that moves a "div" when that div is clicked but it is not working.

```
$(".shape").click(function() {
    var bodyHight = document.body.clientHeight;
    var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    var randomX = Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyWidth));
    var randomY = Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyHeight));
    $(".shape").css("left", randomX);
    $(".shape").css("top", randomY);
});
```

and some css:

```
.shape{
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Typo @ `clientHeight`. Always check console for errors...

Comment: `Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyHeight));` -> double `()` are superfluous here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Like This:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".shape").click(function() {
    var bodyWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    var bodyHight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
    var randomX = Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyWidth));
    var randomY = Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyHight));
    $(".shape").css({top: randomY, left:randomX});
});
});
```

```css
.shape{
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

"bodyHight" on line 2 of the javascript snippet is a typo.

What's more, in most browsers(e.g. Chrome), the default height of  element depends on its internal elements. However, here you use absolute positioning, which means all  are not in DOM stream, which finally leads the height of body to be 0. So div.shape can only move horizontally on the top 1 horizontal pixel line.

Comment: and checking the console for error info is always a good habit.